# while loop to build up a list not ending

Tags: c, list, while-loop, malloc

I'm trying to figure out why my code isn't working but i haven't managed so far. The code should analyse a string and build up a list containing all which letters from the english alphabet (contained in alf) are contained in that string (*s) and how many times:

```
    ` char c, *s, alf[26]={'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
```

the string is then acquired from a file and i've got no problem until there, i've managed to print it out correctly on the prompt so that's working. Anyway here's what i did(int variables d and num will be used later):

```
FILE *f=fopen("prova.txt","r");
int d,l=0,num;
while(feof(f)==0){
    l++;
    fscanf(f,"%c",&c);
}
s=malloc(sizeof(l*sizeof(char)));
rewind(f);
l=0;
while(feof(f)==0){
    fscanf(f,"%c",s+l);
    l++;
}
//"stringa acquisita" stands for "acquired string"
printf("\nstringa acquisita:%s",s);
```

And the string gets printed out correctly, excepting from the fact that it gets one charachter more than it should. Any advices in that direction are also welcome.
So i got to building the list. Here's what I did:

```
typedef struct Nodo{char car; int rip; struct Nodo* next;} Nodo;
typedef Nodo* lista;
lista head = NULL, el, temp;
for(l=0;l<26;l++){
    num=0;
    for(d=0;d<strlen(s);d++){
        if(s[d]==alf[l]){
            num++;
        }
    }
    if(num!=0){
        el = malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
        if(el==NULL){
            perror("error malloc\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        el->car=alf[l];
        el->rip=num;
        if(head==NULL){
            head=el;
            el->next=NULL;
            //this printf doesn't print anything on the prompt
            printf("\n%c\n%d", head->car,head->rip);
        }
        else{
            temp=head;
            while(temp->next!=NULL){
                temp=temp->next;
            }
            temp->next=el;
            el->next=NULL;
        }
    }
    //this printf prints only one time
    printf("CHECKIT\n");
}
```

And here my code crashes. As i specified in the comments, I put two printf to get to see what's going on. The first one doesn't give anything printed on the prompt, about the second one i get one "CHECKIT" printed out and then everything crashes. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?
Thank you a lot.

/**EDIT**/
There was one sizeof more than it should have been:`

```
s=malloc(sizeof(l*sizeof(char)));` `
```

Corrected that with

```
    s=malloc(l*sizeof(char));
```

everything works correctly.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) You should use the return value from `fscanf` to control the loop instead, because `feof` does not do what you think it does. That's where the extra character comes from.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code in a debugger?  If not, please do so.

Comment: Please upgrade to a [mre].

Comment: Your string `s` is not null-terminated. Allocate one byte more and set `s[l] = '\0'` after the second loop. (And fix those loops according to wht Weather Vane said.)

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(l*sizeof(char)))`-- that's clearly one `sizeof` too many. `l * sizeof(char)` is an expression of type `size_t` and the outer `sizeof` will produce the size of that, probably 4 or 8 bytes, no matter what the value of `l` is.

Comment: @MOehm that one sizeof was somehow the problem, now everything is working correctly. Thanks everyone, glad to have joined this beautiful community, this was my first question. I'll try to be more concise and to post more auto-explicative codes in my next ones.